# Flagging Question

Tags: discussion, flagging

I'm still relatively new here, and am enjoying calling this my home. I want to make sure I'm understanding some of the features I'm using so I don't unnecessarily causing the mods work when there shouldn't be. If there's a flagging FAQ that I'm not finding, please point me in that direction.

I had flagged the question [Point to print restrictions in Server2008 NOT R2](https://serverfault.com/questions/288287/point-to-print-restrictions-in-server2008-not-r2) as a possible duplicate. I just wanted clarification as to what is or is not a duplicate.

I'm assuming since in this case it was not a duplicate; it was due to the way the question was asked, or the situation that the user with the question had laid out, and not the actual solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cleared that one. It was a close duplicate, but not an exact one. The asker needed a key piece of information that the dup-candidate didn't have, and that point-to-print is a client-side setting best handled through group policy. Which I then supplied in an answer, and then linked to the dup-candidate since those steps have already been written up.

Comment: Gotcha, so the dup-canidate didn't mention point-to-print, so it wasn't an exact match for the question. Thanks!